# How do I stream Android audio to Windows 10 over bluetooth?

Tags: audio, windows-10, android, bluetooth

I'm trying to stream audio to my Windows 10 PC through my bluetooth adapter (Kensington Bluetooth 4.0 USB Adapter for Laptops (K33956AM)).  I was able to get the device paired with Windows 10 but I can't seem to connect and do anything.  When I try to select my PC from my Android phone's(Lollipop) bluetooth setting nothing happens.  It says paired under my PC name.  I have a Logitech bluetooth adapter hooked up my A/V system and when I select that one it connects fine.

In Windows 10 it shows my android phone in the list of devices and says paired under it but when I select my only option is to "Remove Device".

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for reviving an old thread, but did you make it work? Windows 10 here, also...

Comment: I got it working. I was looking at the suggestion below and when looking through those settings I realized I never downloaded any software for my Bluetooth device so it was just using a generic drive. I went to Kensingtons website and downloaded the software, installed it, and rebooted. After doing that I was able to connect and play audio through my PC.

Comment: A duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1199132/is-there-any-way-to-make-windows-10-act-as-a-a2dp-sink/1556100

Answer (score 4):

- First, make sure your Bluetooth adapter is capable of "A2DP" audio streaming and that you set up the full/all drivers, not only the ones for peer-to-peer services.

  - Right click on Bluetooth > Options / Settings > COM Ports and check if your streaming service is installed there.
- Second, let Windows set up the drivers for your device. Just connect your phone to your PC through USB and wait for Windows to finish installing them. You should get some kind of notification once that's done.
- Last thing, set up your Android's sync program. You can most likely get that from the manufacturer's website.

Last note: You could also stream over WiFi too. Connect your phone and PC to the same network and get one of the countless apps from the app store that lets you stream media to the network, it's easier :)

Comment: What does fully setting up the drivers entail?

Comment: What do COM ports have to do with A2DP?

Comment: How can I 'make sure' my Bluetooth adapter is capable of "A2DP" audio streaming?  Which one is 'my' Bluetooh adapater: the PC or the smartphone? How do I make sure this capability is on? How do I set up the full/all drivers, not only the ones for peer-to-peer services."  ??

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 10 versions released before Windows 10 May 2020 Update, Microsoft had implemented support for the A2DP source role, but not for the SINK role for desktop editions. This means you could use Intel Bluetooth on Windows 10 to send audio to other Bluetooth devices, such as a speaker, but you wasn’t be able to receive audio from other Bluetooth devices via A2DP.

Starting in Windows 10 version 2004, Microsoft has re-added the SINK role to Windows 10 for upcoming versions of the OS. However, to use the feature, you need to install a third party app [Bluetooth Audio Receiver](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N9WCLWDQS5J) from Microsoft Store, as the OS lacks the user interface to activate the SINK role. This app should be running to be able to stream audio from Android to Windows 10 speakers over Bluetooth.

The instruction can be found here: [Enable and Use A2DP Sink for Bluetooth in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/enable-and-use-a2dp-sink-for-bluetooth-in-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0):

If you possess Asus device, you can use Asus AOLink built-in app for that.

1. Enable DLNA (is enabled by default if you didn't change this setting)
2. Enable Home Group
3. [Install WMPlayer](https://betanews.com/2017/10/09/windows-10-update-removes-windows-media-player/) in Windows 10
4. Then you will be able to stream music [like this](https://www.asus.com/ua/support/FAQ/1004097/).

This app seems to be outdated, but just in case. Just in case you have old Asus.