# I want to stream my Android 7.0 audio from my phone to my Windows 10 PC through Bluetooth or USB without any apps

Tags: windows-10, audio, android, bluetooth

I have already googled, but there was no solution. As suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/958184/how-do-i-stream-android-audio-to-windows-10-over-bluetooth) I took a look at com ports but incoming ones had no options. My devices are a surface pro 2017 and a S7 Edge exynos variant.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the phone is connected to your computer via the original USB cable and that it’s powered on.

From the top edge of the screen, swipe down your finger to pull down the notification shade.

You should be able to see the USB options so touch on it to view other options.

Touch Media Device (MTP) to be able to transfer media files.

Or you may touch Camera (PTP) if you just want to transfer photos via the Camera app.

You can check in developer options and I think somewhere else I forget exactly where, but you can change the usb from things like charging, file transfer, pic transfer, etc.

On the other hand, if you are using the latest Windows 10 1709 version, there is a setting option called Phone in Settings app, you could also try it, but need to enter your phone number.
[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question